# When connect server xmpp has error

Tags: android, xmpp

Has anyone used androidpn？ When I connect server, xmpp has this error:

```
02-27 21:24:34.720: D/RegisterTask.PacketListener(3144): packet=<iq id="8dMsj-0" from="kwant.cn" type="error"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:register"><password>abc</password><username>abc</username></query><error code="400" type="MODIFY"><bad-request xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>
02-27 21:24:34.720: E/Androidpn_XmppManager(3144): Unknown error while registering XMPP account! bad-request
```

It hints: XMPP connected successfully. But it can not login in all the time. I do not know why.

Comment: You get a XMPP error 'bad-request' back from the server. It's hard to tell what's going on here without seeing at least every XMPP stanza involved in the login process.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following code for connecting and sign-in using Smack API in Android and it runs like a charm:

```
        private XMPPClient xmppClient;
        private XMPPConnection connection;
        private ArrayList<String> messages = new ArrayList(); 



public void login(String userName, String password) throws XMPPException
            {
            ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("HOST",PORT, "SERVICE");
            connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
            connection.connect();

            //LOGIN USING THE FOLLWING login() 

            connection.login(userName, password);
            xmppClient.setConnection(connection); 
            }
```